# Title disappears from div when gradient applied

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have several divs on my page. Each of them has the title attribute so the user can mouse over them to get more information. Until today, they were very plain backgrounds (I was working on layout/functionality before I moved onto style), and the title worked as expected. Now I have added a gradient background, and the title no longer appears.

The browser involved is IE8.

HTML:

```
<div title='' class="mywrapclass"> <!-- no title because an outer wrapper has a title I want to suppress here -->
    <div title="More information..." style="width:40px;height:50px" class="myclass"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myclass
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom:none;
    bottom:0%;
    position:absolute;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType="1", startColorstr='#87aaff', endColorstr='#000044');
}

.mywrapclass
{
    background-color:White;
    position:absolute;
    left:58%;
    width:32%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I get the title to work again?

Comment: When I try it in IE8, the "title" tooltip appears when I mouse over some text inside the DIV, but not when I mouse over the background where there is no text.

Comment: The divs in this case contain no text. The 'title' tooltip appeared on mousing over the background before it was a gradient. Since there will not be text in these, I need it to appear when mousing over the background.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve -- when I apply that gradient to an empty div, the gradient doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Sorry, but your `myclass` div still doesn't show up because it has no content and no dimension.

Comment: @mblase75 sorry, forgot to include the width/height. They are set dynamically in the html at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `background-color` to `.myclass`. The `title` will now pop up on hover. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/TbdAm/

```
.myclass{     
    background-color: white; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom:none;
    top:0%;
    position:absolute;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType="1", startColorstr='#87aaff', endColorstr='#000044');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be two issues here:

1. You may need to set `-ms-filter` for IE8.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx
2. Even though you set the `height` and `width` inline, IE may still have issues with `haslayout`.  Fix that by adding `zoom:1;` to your `.myclass`

**EDIT**

As per comment

> Using -ms-filter instead of filter causes the gradient not to render,
>   but the title works.

Try using quotes, as per MS docs

> When you use -ms-filter, enclose the progid in single quotes (') or
>   double quotes ("). Use commas (,) to separate multiple values, as
>   shown in the Examples section.

So pick one set of quotes for enclosing the `progid` and another for those inside the `progid`.  See if that works

Comment: Using -ms-filter instead of filter causes the gradient not to render, but the title works.

Comment: Following your edit, it now renders, but there is still no title (with or without zoom:1;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a "wild" guess here as I haven't used this method before but try removing the quotes around the 1 for GradientType

Comment: No luck. Tried with double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes. Still not title.